# PHP - Get JSON body from HTTPS request

Tags: php, json, https

I have some PHP files that access some JSON in the request body and then acts on it.

I get the JSON using:

```
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$input = json_decode($json, TRUE);
```

And access the values using:

```
$input["val"]
```

However, I just upgraded to HTTPS and have deduced that is not reading/receiving any JSON.

How do you get JSON data out of a HTTPS request?

Comment: Are you redirecting the http to https?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Discovered my issue - I was sending a GET request and not a POST request.

For some reason, that was working without HTTPS so I didn't think that was the issue. Fixed now!

Answer (score 0):

**Case 1:** 
From the details provided in the question my best guess is your target server does not have a valid SSL certificate.

**Case 2**
Your server doesn't have https wrapper available for the php script. Check the output of the following script.

```
<?php

$wrappers = stream_get_wrappers();
echo 'openssl: ',  extension_loaded  ('openssl') ? 'yes':'no', "\n";
echo 'http wrapper: ', in_array('http', $wrappers) ? 'yes':'no', "\n";
echo 'https wrapper: ', in_array('https', $wrappers) ? 'yes':'no', "\n";
echo 'wrappers: ', var_export($wrappers);
```

Comment: It is a valid SSL and I'm hosting using a hosting service. This is the output: openssl: yes http wrapper: yes https wrapper: yes wrappers: array ( 0 => 'https', 1 => 'ftps', 2 => 'compress.zlib', 3 => 'compress.bzip2', 4 => 'php', 5 => 'file', 6 => 'glob', 7 => 'data', 8 => 'http', 9 => 'ftp', 10 => 'phar', 11 => 'zip', )

Comment: It'd be more helpful if we can get more info. May be the resource URL.

Answer (score 0):

Keep an eye out for cross-site https issues.  Your browser will less tolerant when using https, than just when using plain http .  For example, once your main site is https, your support scripts will also need to be https.

I suggest you look closely at your browser's 'network' tab and look for any other clues.

I hope this points you in the right direction.

--- Further Investigation ---

- Can you copy and paste the original code into your answer?

Can you try these (hunting for clues)..

```
print "<br>json: '$json'";
print "<br> type: ".gettype($json);
print "<br> last error: ".json_last_error();
```

Comment: Not 100% sure what you mean about the support scripts, but I'm just sending some JSON to a single .php page like 'example.co.uk/test.php' and the Network tab just shows a 200 for that page

Comment: Ok - since you're seeing 200, it doesn't sound like my clue.  I ran into a situation when the main page went from http to https, and the browser start forcing the js on the page to also come from http. Whereas, when the main page is http, the browser will allow a mix of http and https.

Comment: I added a 'Further investigation' section to my answer - I hope this helps.